# Glassfish error while creating a LDAP realm: "Invalid property syntax, "=" in value

Tags: java, netbeans, ldap, glassfish

I'm trying to create a LDAP realm in Glassfish 4.0 (build 89) but every time I tried so far, the following error occurred:

> "Invalid property syntax, "=" in value: base-dn=\[...]"

[image: Screenshot (Imgur)]

I tried using different browsers and reinstalled Glassfish in Netbeans. The strange thing is that a friend of mine could copy my base-dn and it worked.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Glassfish 4.0. It throws this error if a property contains an equals sign (=). 
See the following JIRA Issues:

- [GLASSFISH-20744 Problems saving property values for Realms](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20744)
- [GLASSFISH-20693 - Cannot create com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm in GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 (build 89)](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20693)
- [GLASSFISH-16198 Admin UI requires LDAP search filter values to be double-quoted](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16198)

This error doesn't occur in GlassFish 3.x, this may be the reason that it worked when your friend tried it.

**Workaround:** As a workaround you can just take some value without an equals sign, like e.g. `abc` and save that. This should successfully create the LDAP realm. Then click on the created realm to edit the property. Now you can replace `abc` with the desired value (and it can also contains equals signs), save again and you are done.

Comment: You are a saint. Thank you so much mate!

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove al `dc=` like this:

Before:

```
dc=hello,dc=world
```

After:

```
hello, world
```

Then, you can save it.
When it is effectively saved, you can edit it and let it in the correct form `dc=hello,dc=world`

This works for me